# How do I include apostrophes in my chat (using php and mysqli for the database)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a little chatbox on my website and it has a simple php code I've put together to check for any undesired tags, and also a sort of psuedo bbcode for basic color and bold and stuff. It saves the chat to a datatable on my server. My problem is that any time a user has an apostrophe it won't go through. Even when commenting out the strip_tags. I thought about just finding them in the string and replacing them with some other key, but then it'd replace any instance of that key and when converting back to an apostrophe it could screw up the actual line of text (for example if users do a - symbol but I'm using that as the replacement for apostrophes, when converted back from - to apostrophe it'd mess their symbol up).

Any clear way to go about fixing this problem?

updateChat.php:

```
<html><body>
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');


    exit;
}

    require_once 'dbconnection.php';
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

    $qry = ('SELECT ChatText FROM Chat LIMIT 20');
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

    $submittext=$_POST["submittext"];
    $user= $_SESSION['name'];
    $posttext = "[b]" .$user. ":[/b] " .$submittext. "";

    if(!empty($submittext)) { 
        if(!empty($user)){
            if($submittext != strip_tags($submittext)) {
            // contains HTML
            }
            else{
            $sql="INSERT INTO Chat (ChatText) VALUES ('$posttext')";
            if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){}
            }
        }
    }

?>
</body></html>
```

getChat.php:

```
<html><body>
<?php
    require_once 'dbconnection.php';
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    $chatarray = array();

    $qry = ('SELECT ChatText FROM Chat');
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)   // checking if there is any row in the resultset
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))  // Iterate for each rows
        {
            $chatarray[] = $row['ChatText'];
        }
    }

    foreach (array_reverse($chatarray) as $chat)
        {
        $newmessage = $chat;
        $newmessage = nl2br($newmessage);
        $newmessage = wordwrap($newmessage, 34, "\n", true);

        $bbcode = array("[b]", "[/b]", "[red]", "[blue]", "[green]", "[purple]", "[/color]");
        $htmlcode = array("<b>", "</b>", "<span style='color:red'>", "<span style='color:blue'>", "<span style='color:green'>", "<span style='color:purple'>", "</span>");
        $newmessage = str_replace($bbcode, $htmlcode, $newmessage);

        $btagfixes = "";
        $stagfixes = "";

        $numbold = substr_count($newmessage, "<b>");
        $numboldclosed = substr_count($newmessage, "</b>");
        if ($numbold > $numboldclosed)
        {
            $cnt = $numbold - $numboldclosed;
            while ($cnt > 0)
            {
                $btagfixes .="</b>";

                $cnt --;
            }
        }

        $numspan = substr_count($newmessage, "<span");
        $numspanclosed = substr_count($newmessage, "</span>");
        if ($numspan > $numspanclosed)
        {
            $cnt = $numspan - $numspanclosed;
            while ($cnt > 0)
            {
                $stagfixes .="</span>";

                $cnt --;
            }
        }
        echo "<span class='adv_chat_p'>";
        echo $newmessage. "" .$btagfixes. "" .$stagfixes."</span></br></br>";
        }

?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements with parameters rather than substituting variables into the SQL string.

Comment: @Barmar would you mind giving me an example of what you mean? I know how to bind parameters but that in particular doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Why doesn't it solve your issue? `$sql="INSERT INTO Chat (ChatText) VALUES (?)";` should solve it.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I'm not sure how binding the parameters resolves the issue of apostrophes being included. Even if I did that it wouldn't change the issue as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the issue? How are the apostrophes causing a problem if it's not when they're substituted into the SQL?

Comment: I know it's not strictly about SQL injection, but the solution for that also solves any other syntax problems due to special characters being substituted into the query.

Comment: @Barmar I need the actual line of text that is being sent into the database to keep the apostrophe but there is some sort of issue where it is not sending anything that has an apostrophe through, and I'm not getting any sort of error to see why. This happens regardless if I bind.

Example:
```
            $sql="INSERT INTO Chat (ChatText) VALUES (?)";
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $posttext);
```

makes no difference.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that wouldn't let the apostrophe through. But instead of all this `strip_tags()` cleanup, just use `htmlentities()` when inserting the query results into the output page. Then everything should be shown literally.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know why either, that's why I made the question, lol. But since it's clearly not a duplicate can that please be removed? Even removing strip_tags (as I mentioned in the post) makes zero difference. And I do want to keep the strip. I don't want players being able to add html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257298/discussion-between-barmar-and-literally-mom).

Comment:  [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: How do you know it is not returning an error? You don't seem to be checking for errors. Did you configure mysqli to throw exceptions?

Comment: I have voted to reopen your question, because of your insistence that it is not solved by using query parameters, and therefore not a duplicate of typical answers that say "use query parameters to avoid SQL injection errors."

Comment: @BillKarwin this problem will be solved by using query parameters. Using single quites in an input pix is a typical form of sql injection attacks (yes, I know that there can be valid reasons of having single quotes in text), so the typical solution is to use the sql injection prevention techniques. The alternative would be escaping the inpit, but we all know that is not a really gteat option.

Comment: @Shadow Normally I would agree with you, but I recommend to read the chat log that Barmar had with the OP. It's not as simple as using parameters in this case.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have read the comments before voting to close again. Defending against the single quote is best done through parametrised queries. The OP can still strip html tags from the input before binding any parameters and that was not part of the question. Btw, even the canonical answer for handling single quotes is closed as duplicate of the sql injection question.

Comment: @LiterallyMom In case it is still not an issue with prepared statement: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which will show the exact problem with the apostrophe you have when the PHP script is run. Your code should already be updated to use prepared statements.

Comment: @BillKarwin we cannot reopen a question based on an unfounded claim in the *chat*. Speaking of the *present question*, it's a trivial case about a failed query. [Here you can see this exact code reproduced](https://phpize.online/s/V4). With a single quote in the data, it's indeed "doesn't make through". So based on the code provided, this question *must* be closed. Only I changed the dupe target as formally this question is not about SQL injection (though the remedy is the same) and that mention irritates the OP.

Comment: So all we got is a claim in the chat that apostrophes "get removed". That's a completely different problem, which [cannot be backed by the present code as well](https://phpize.online/s/G4). As you can see, an apostrophe, once in the database,  "makes it through". Which makes us think that apostrophes get removed somewhere *before* this code (probably as an attempt to tackle a failed query). But this alleged behavior cannot be count towards opening the present question.